# Bitbucket pipelines extract files from artifacts dist/

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm have a question about my pipeline of bitbucket.
I do the deploy directly in my server in production.
But when the command are completed I find in my server my folder dist.
I would only the file inside the folder dist
this is my code:

```
#bitbucket-pipelines.yml
image: node:latest

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: Build VUE Project
        caches:
            - node
        script:
            - yarn install
            - yarn run build
        artifacts:
          - dist/**
    - step:
        name: Deploy to CPANEL
        deployment: production
        script:
          - pipe: (....something)
            variables:
              USER: $ftp_user
              PASSWORD: $ftp_password
              SERVER: $ftp_host
              REMOTE_PATH: $ftp_remote_path
```

So when the pipeline is completed I found in my production server the folder dist(with my app inside)
How can extract all files from dist in the pipelines files?Someone have suggestions?Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

For everyone will have same problem the solution is to add this line inside step:

```
LOCAL_PATH: 'dist'
```

So, only the content of the directory dist will be deployed!
Have a nice coding day :)

Comment: I have the same issue that in 2nd deployment when I check with `ls` the dist folder seems missing. In first step it is showing once I check with `ls` 
Please help me with this